# key [turn] doesn't

Tags: tikz-pgf

According to the manual (http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf p. 142) the following code is sound

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- (1,1) -- ([turn]-45:1cm) -- ([turn]-30:1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(actually, this is just an example from the manual). Unfortunately, I get the error that "tikz/turn" is unknown. What's wrong? Perhaps this key is part of some library (in contradiction to the manual)?

Comment: It works for me. May be you need an update of tex distribution.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). This also works for me, so I'd recommend you upgrade to TeXLive2014. Otherwise you can add `\listfiles` just _before_ `\begin{document}` and post the output in the log file here, and we can compare with ours to determine exactly which specific file is out of date.

Comment: yes, in texlive2014 this code works |-> upgrade

Comment: If you do `texdoc tikz` in a terminal/command line, you'll get the documentation of the TikZ version you have installed.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was solved by updating the tikz/pgf package.